# TCP sockets, send files, client server, server doest save a whole file, C language

Tags: c, sockets, server, tcp, client

I wrote a simple protocol in which Im able to exchange files / text messages between client and server. If the client send a text to server, server should simply echo it back. On the other hand, when client send a special command (for example, `SEND_TXT_FILE`) server should receive a file uploaded by client to the server.

I almost got it work. However, there's still problem with sending files. Sever does not save the whole file, it only creates it and disconnects.

Here's the protocol:

```
CLIENT ---------- text1 ----------> SERVER
CLIENT <---------- text1 ---------- SERVER
CLIENT ---------- text2 ----------> SERVER
CLIENT <---------- text3 ---------- SERVER
CLIENT ---------- SENDTXTFILE ----------> SERVER
CLIENT <---------- OK ---------- SERVER
CLIENT ---------- FILENAME ----------> SERVER
CLIENT <---------- OK ---------- SERVER
CLIENT ---------- file content ----------> SERVER
CLIENT <--------- FILE_UPLOADED --------- SERVER
CLIENT ---------- text3 ----------> SERVER
CLIENT <---------- text3 ---------- SERVER
```

How can I solve this?

**server.c**

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int send_all(int sockfd, const char *buf, int len)
{
    ssize_t n;

    while (len > 0)
    {
        n = send(sockfd, buf, len, 0);
        if (n < 0)
            return -1;
        buf += n;
        len -= n;
    }

    return 0;
}

int recv_all(int sockfd, char *buf, int len)
{
    ssize_t n;

    while (len > 0)
    {
        n = recv(sockfd, buf, len, 0);
        if (n <= 0)
            return n;
        buf += n;
        len -= n;
    }

    return 1;
}

int recv_txt_file(int sockfd, int len, const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    int total = 0, b = 0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    memset(buffer, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        while (recv_all(sockfd, buffer, len) != 1)
        {
            total += b;
            fwrite(buffer, 1, b, fp);
        }

        printf("Received byte: %d\n",total);
        if (b < 0)
            perror("Receiving");

        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        perror("File");
    }
    close(sockfd);
}

int main()
{
    int port = 6666;
    int server_fd, client_fd, read;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE], filename[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char remote_ip[16];
    int remote_port, res = 0;

    server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    int optval = 1;
    setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void *)&optval, sizeof(int));

    memset(&server, '\0', sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not bind socket");
        close(server_fd);
        return 1;
    }

    if (listen(server_fd, 1) < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not listen on socket");
        close(server_fd);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Server TCP is listening on port %d ... \n", port);

    socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client);
    client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_len);

    if (client_fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not establish new connection");
        close(server_fd);
        return 1;
    }

    remote_port = ntohs(client.sin_port);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, remote_ip, sizeof(remote_ip));

    printf("Client IP address: %s, port %d\n", remote_ip, remote_port);

    while (1)
    {
        read = recv_all(client_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (read <= 0)
        {
            if (read < 0)
                perror("Client read failed");
            else
                printf("Client disconnected\n");
            break;
        }

        if ((res = strcmp(buffer, "SENDFILE_TXT\n") == 0))
        {

            printf("-------FROM CLIENT: %s-------\n", buffer);
            memset(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, '\0');
            strcpy(buffer, "OK");
            if (send_all(client_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) < 0)
            {
                perror("Client write failed");
                break;
            }
            read = recv_all(client_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (read <= 0)
            {
                if (read < 0)
                    perror("Client read failed");
                else
                    printf("Client disconnected\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("-------FROM CLIENT: %s-------\n", buffer);
            memset(filename, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE);
            strcpy(filename, buffer);
            memset(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, '\0');
            strcpy(buffer, "OK");
            if (send_all(client_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) < 0)
            {
                perror("Client write failed");
                break;
            }
            recv_txt_file(client_fd, BUFFER_SIZE, filename);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("FROM CLIENT: %.*s\n", BUFFER_SIZE, buffer);

            if (send_all(client_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) < 0)
            {
                perror("Client write failed");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    close(client_fd);
    close(server_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

**client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

socklen_t hostname_to_ip_port(char *hostname, int port, struct sockaddr_storage *addr)
{
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo;
    int rv;

    char service[20];
    sprintf(service, "%d", port);

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(hostname, service, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 0;
    }

    socklen_t addrlen = servinfo->ai_addrlen;
    memcpy(addr, servinfo->ai_addr, addrlen);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    return addrlen;
}

int send_all(int sockfd, const char *buf, size_t len)
{
    ssize_t n;

    while (len > 0)
    {
        n = send(sockfd, buf, len, 0);
        if (n < 0)
            return -1;
        buf += n;
        len -= n;
    }

    return 0;
}

int recv_all(int sockfd, char *buf, int len)
{
    ssize_t n;

    while (len > 0)
    {
        n = recv(sockfd, buf, len, 0);
        if (n <= 0)
            return n;
        buf += n;
        len -= n;
    }

    return 1;
}

long int get_file_size(char filename[])
{
    // opening the file in read mode
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    // checking if the file exist or not
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File Not Found!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);

    // calculating the size of the file
    long int res = ftell(fp);

    // closing the file
    fclose(fp);

    return res;
}

int send_txt_file(int sockfd, int len, const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    int b;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    memset(buffer, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while openning file");
        return 0;
    }

    while ((b = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, fp)) > 0){
        send_all(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        memset(buffer, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 6666;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE], fname[BUFFER_SIZE];

    int sockfd, err, res;
    struct sockaddr_storage server_addr;
    socklen_t server_addr_len;

    server_addr_len = hostname_to_ip_port(hostname, port, &server_addr);
    if (server_addr_len == 0)
        return 1;

    sockfd = socket(server_addr.ss_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, server_addr_len) < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not connect socket");
        return 1;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        memset(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, '\0');
        memset(fname, BUFFER_SIZE, '\0');

        printf("> ");
        if (!fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin))
            break;

        if (strstr(buffer, "SENDFILE_TXT") != NULL)
        {
            if (send_all(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) < 0)
            {
                perror("Could not send message");
                close(sockfd);
                return 1;
            }

            memset(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, '\0');
            err = recv_all(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (err <= 0)
            {
                if (err < 0)
                    perror("Could not read message");
                else
                    printf("Server disconnected\n");
                break;
            }
            if ((res = strcmp(buffer, "OK") == 0))
            {
                printf("-------FROM SERVER: %s-------\n", buffer);

                printf("Give filename> ");
                memset(fname, BUFFER_SIZE, '\0');
                if (!fgets(fname, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin))
                    break;
                if (send_all(sockfd, fname, BUFFER_SIZE) < 0)
                {
                    perror("Could not send message");
                    close(sockfd);
                    return 1;
                }
            }

            err = recv_all(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (err <= 0)
            {
                if (err < 0)
                    perror("Could not read message");
                else
                    printf("Server disconnected\n");
                break;
            }

            fname[strlen(fname)-1] = 0;
            printf("----%s----\n", fname);
            send_txt_file(sockfd, BUFFER_SIZE, fname);

            printf("FROM SERVER: %.*s\n", BUFFER_SIZE, buffer);
        }
        else
        {
            if (send_all(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) < 0)
            {
                perror("Could not send message");
                close(sockfd);
                return 1;
            }

            err = recv_all(sockfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (err <= 0)
            {
                if (err < 0)
                    perror("Could not read message");
                else
                    printf("Server disconnected\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("FROM SERVER: %.*s\n", BUFFER_SIZE, buffer);
        }
    }

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220855/discussion-on-question-by-brian-brown-tcp-sockets-send-files-client-server-se).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are using `send_txt_file()` and `recv_txt_file()` to transfer a file is not correct.

---

On the server side:

When a client connects, the server waits for the client to send *exactly* `BUFFER_SIZE` (1024) bytes for each command, no more, no less (which is a waste of bandwidth for short commands).  When a `SENDFILE_TXT` command is received, the server reads the filename from the client (which will cause a buffer overflow if the filename is *exactly* `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes in length), and then calls `recv_txt_file()`.

`recv_txt_file()` *attempts* to read from the client in a loop, reading in *exactly* `BUFFER_SIZE` chunks.  However, the `while` loop being used is coded incorrectly. It is checking the return value of `recv_all()` for *failure*, not for *success*.  The `!=` check needs to be changed to `==` instead.  And also, the `b` variable that is being used to increment `total`, and tell `fwrite()` how many bytes to write, is never set to any value *other than 0*. It needs to be set to `BUFFER_SIZE` instead, since that is how many bytes have actually been read if `recv_all()` returns 1.

However, even if the `while` loop were coded properly, the transfer would still not operate properly, because it *requires* the file to be sent in *even multiples* of `BUFFER_SIZE`.  If the file is not an even multiple in size, `recv_all()` will end up waiting for data that the client does not send, until an error occurs on the socket.

Also, `recv_txt_file()` is closing the connection after the transfer is finished.  It should not do that, as that will prevent the client from being able to send further commands after sending a file. The client is not closing its end of the connection after sending a file, so the server should not be closing its end after receiving a file.

---

On the client side:

When the client sends a `SENDFILE_TXT` command and gets an acknowledgement back, it calls `send_txt_file()`, which reads the file in a loop, sending it to the server in `BUFFER_SIZE` sized chunks.  If the file size is not an even multiple of `BUFFER_SIZE`, the last block sent will just waste bandwidth and send random garbage to the server.  Also, you are ignoring the return value of `send_all()` to break the loop if an error occurs on the socket.

---

The client should send the actual file size to the server before sending the file data.  The server can then read that size value first so it knows when to stop reading.

That being said, try something more like the following:

**server.c**

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int send_all(int sockfd, const void *buf, int len)
{
    ssize_t n;
    const char *pbuf = (const char*) buf;

    while (len > 0)
    {
        n = send(sockfd, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            perror("Client write failed");
            return n;
        }
        pbuf += n;
        len -= n;
    }

    return 0;
}

int send_uint32(int sockfd, uint32_t value)
{
    value = htonl(value);
    if (send_all(sockfd, &value, sizeof(value)) < 0)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

int send_str(int sockfd, const char *s)
{
    uint32_t len = strlen(s);
    int res = send_uint32(sockfd, len);
    if (res == 0)
        res = send_all(sockfd, s, len);
    return res;
}

int recv_all(int sockfd, void * buf, int len)
{
    ssize_t n;
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;

    while (len > 0)
    {
        n = recv(sockfd, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (n <= 0)
        {
            if (n < 0)
                perror("Client read failed");
            else
                printf("Client disconnected\n");
            return n;
        }
        pbuf += n;
        len -= n;
    }

    return 1;
}

int recv_uint32(int sockfd, uint32_t *value)
{
    int res = recv_all(sockfd, value, sizeof(*value));
    if (res > 0)
        *value = ntohl(*value);
    return res;
}

int recv_uint64(int sockfd, uint64_t *value)
{
    int res = recv_all(sockfd, value, sizeof(*value));
    if (res > 0)
        *value = ntohll(*value); // <-- use any implementation of your choosing...
    return res;
}

int recv_str(int sockfd, char **str)
{
    uint32_t len;

    int res = recv_uint32(sockfd, &len);
    if (res <= 0)
        return res;

    *str = (char*) malloc(len + 1);
    if (*str == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not allocate memory");
        return -1;
    }

    res = recv_all(sockfd, *str, len);
    if (res <= 0)
        free(*str);
    else
        (*str)[len] = '\0';

    return res;
}

int recv_txt_file(int sockfd)
{
    char *filename;
    uint64_t filesize;

    if (recv_str(sockfd, &filename) <= 0)
        return -1;

    int res = recv_uint64(sockfd, &filesize);
    if (res <= 0)
    {
        free(filename);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("-------FROM CLIENT: %s-------\n", filename);

    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not create file");
        free(filename);
        send_str(sockfd, "NO");
        return 0;
    }

    free(filename);

    // optional: pre-size the new file to the specified filesize...

    if (send_str(sockfd, "OK") < 0)
        return -1;

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int b;
    uint64_t total = 0;

    while (filesize > 0)
    {
        b = (filesize > BUFFER_SIZE) ? BUFFER_SIZE : (int) filesize;

        res = recv_all(sockfd, buffer, b);
        if (res <= 0)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            return -1;
        }

        if (fwrite(buffer, b, 1, fp) < 1)
        {
            perror("Could not write to file");
            fclose(fp);
            send_str(sockfd, "ERROR");
            return -1;
        }

        total += b;
        filesize -= b;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Received bytes: %lu\n", total);

    if (send_str(sockfd, "OK") < 0)
        return -1;

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int port = 6666;
    int server_fd, client_fd, read;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char filename[BUFFER_SIZE], *cmd;
    char remote_ip[16];
    int remote_port, res = 0;

    server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    int optval = 1;
    setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(int));

    memset(&server, '\0', sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not bind socket");
        close(server_fd);
        return 1;
    }

    if (listen(server_fd, 1) < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not listen on socket");
        close(server_fd);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Server TCP is listening on port %d ... \n", port);

    socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client);
    client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client_len);

    if (client_fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not establish new connection");
        close(server_fd);
        return 1;
    }

    remote_port = ntohs(client.sin_port);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, remote_ip, sizeof(remote_ip));

    printf("Client IP address: %s, port %d\n", remote_ip, remote_port);

    while (recv_str(client_fd, &cmd) > 0)
    {
        printf("-------FROM CLIENT: %s-------\n", cmd);

        if (strcmp(cmd, "SENDFILE_TXT") == 0)
        {
            if (recv_txt_file(client_fd) < 0)
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (send_str(client_fd, cmd) < 0)
            {
                free(cmd);
                break;
            }
        }

        free(cmd);
    }

    close(client_fd);
    close(server_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

**client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

socklen_t hostname_to_ip_port(char *hostname, int port, struct sockaddr_storage *addr)
{
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo;
    int rv;

    char service[20];
    sprintf(service, "%d", port);

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(hostname, service, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 0;
    }

    socklen_t addrlen = servinfo->ai_addrlen;
    memcpy(addr, servinfo->ai_addr, addrlen);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    return addrlen;
}

int send_all(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len)
{
    ssize_t n;
    const char *pbuf = (const char *) buf;

    while (len > 0)
    {
        n = send(sockfd, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            perror("Server write failed");
            return n;
        }
        pbuf += n;
        len -= n;
    }

    return 0;
}

int send_uint32(int sockfd, uint32_t value)
{
    value = htonl(value);
    return send_all(sockfd, &value, sizeof(value));
}

int send_uint64(int sockfd, uint64_t value)
{
    value = htonll(value); // <-- use any implementation of your choosing...
    return send_all(sockfd, &value, sizeof(value));
}

int send_str(int sockfd, const char *s)
{
    uint32_t len = strlen(s);
    int res = send_uint32(sockfd, len);
    if (res == 0)
        res = send_all(sockfd, s, len);
    return res;
}

int recv_all(int sockfd, void *buf, int len)
{
    ssize_t n;
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;

    while (len > 0)
    {
        n = recv(sockfd, pbuf, len, 0);
        if (n <= 0)
        {
            if (n < 0)
                perror("Server read failed");
            else
                printf("Server disconnected\n");
            return n;
        }
        pbuf += n;
        len -= n;
    }

    return 1;
}

int recv_uint32(int sockfd, uint32_t *value)
{
    int res = recv_all(sockfd, value, sizeof(*value));
    if (res > 0)
        *value = ntohl(*value);
    return res;
}

int recv_str(int sockfd, char **str)
{
    uint32_t len;

    int res = recv_uint32(sockfd, &len);
    if (res <= 0)
        return res;

    *str = (char*) malloc(len + 1);
    if (*str == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not allocate memory");
        return -1;
    }

    res = recv_all(sockfd, *str, len);
    if (res <= 0)
        free(*str);
    else
        (*str)[len] = '\0';

    return res;
}

int send_txt_file(int sockfd, const char *filename)
{
    char *resp;
    int res;
    long int filesize;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int b;

    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    if (filesize < 0)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    if (send_str(sockfd, "SENDFILE_TXT") < 0)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    if (send_str(sockfd, filename) < 0)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    if (send_uint64(sockfd, filesize) < 0)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    res = recv_str(sockfd, &resp);
    if (res <= 0)
        return -1;

    printf("-------FROM SERVER: %s-------\n", resp);

    if (strcmp(resp, "OK") != 0)
    {
        free(resp);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    free(resp);

    while (filesize > 0)
    {
        b = (filesize > BUFFER_SIZE) ? BUFFER_SIZE : (int) filesize;

        b = fread(buffer, 1, b, fp);
        if (b < 1)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            return -1;
        }

        if (send_all(sockfd, buffer, b) < 0)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            return -1;
        }

        filesize -= b;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    res = recv_str(sockfd, &resp);
    if (res <= 0)
        return -1;

    printf("-------FROM SERVER: %s-------\n", resp);

    free(resp);

    return 0;
}

int prompt(const char *text, char **input)
{
    *input = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;

    printf("%s> ", text);

    ssize_t len = getline(input, &size, stdin);
    if (len < 0)
        return len;

    if ((*input)[len-1] == '\n')
    {
        --len;
        (*input)[len] = '\0';
    }

    return len;
}

int main()
{
    char *hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 6666;
    char *cmd, *resp, *fname;
    size_t size;
    ssize_t len;

    int sockfd, res;
    struct sockaddr_storage server_addr;
    socklen_t server_addr_len;

    server_addr_len = hostname_to_ip_port(hostname, port, &server_addr);
    if (server_addr_len == 0)
        return 1;

    sockfd = socket(server_addr.ss_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, server_addr_len) < 0)
    {
        perror("Could not connect socket");
        return 1;
    }

    while (prompt("", &cmd) >= 0)
    {
        if (strcmp(cmd, "SENDFILE_TXT") == 0)
        {
            if (prompt("Give filename", &fname) < 0)
                break;

            if (send_txt_file(sockfd, fname) < 0)
                break;

            free(fname);
        }
        else
        {
            if (send_str(sockfd, cmd) < 0)
            {
                free(cmd);
                close(sockfd);
                return 1;
            }

            if (recv_str(sockfd, &resp) <= 0)
                break;

            printf("FROM SERVER: %s\n", resp);
            free(resp);
        }

        free(cmd);
    }

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a bunch of errors in your code. It even does not compile. After fixing the errors, client connects and thats it - server ends its work, so the client is not able to send anything.

Comment: @yak I didn't have access to a compiler when I initially wrote this answer. I have now corrected the compiler errors, and when I test the 2 apps, the client is able to communicate with the server and send both text messages and files, and get responses back.

Answer (score 3):

regarding:

```
int total = 0, b = 0;
```

and

```
while(recv_all(sockfd, buffer, len) != 1)
{
    total += b;
    fwrite(buffer, 1, b, fp);
```

the `total` and `b` never move from their initial value of 0.  So 0 bytes are written to the output file.

Comment: The return value of `recv_all()` is not a byte count. It returns `< 0` on failure, `0` on graceful disconnect, and `1` if `len` bytes is read into `buffer`. So you need to add `b = len;` when `recv_all()` returns `1` before then using `b` anywhere else. Otherwise, get rid of `b` and just use `total += len;` and `fwrite(buffer, 1, len, fp);` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau,  what about when less than `len`  bytes are read?  Strongly suggest the function: recv_all()` return the actual number of bytes read.   Also, the function: `recv()` will stall/block when there are no more bytes sent by the other end of the connection, but has not hungup.   Suggest becoming familiar with  the function: `select()` and use a 'timeout` value

Comment: I'm well aware of how `recv()` and `select()` work. I've been doing socket programing for over 20 years. `recv_all()` is designed to be an all-or-nothing kind of function, hence its name. Either it reads *all* of the requested `len` bytes, or it fails with an error/disconnect. There is no in-between. So, there is no need for its return value to return the actual number of bytes read. If it returns 1 then it is guaranteed to have actually read exactly `len` bytes, no more, no less.

Comment: @RemyLebeau,  Suggest re-coding the function: `read_all()` because it (currently) results in problems in the reading of data from the other end of the connection

Comment: "*it (currently) results in problems in the reading of data from the other end of the connection*" - no, it doesn't.  And I've been doing this kind of coding for a LONG time, so I know that it works just fine. The caller is expecting exactly `len` bytes, so `recv_all()` waits for exactly `len` byes to be read. Blocking is fine. Either the peer sends what is expected, or the connection is in a bad state, in which case a timeout can be enabled to make the read fail.

Comment: the problem stated in the question is that not all the input file is received.  I just gave you the reason the file was not fully transferred.  Rather than arguing about it, how about actually stepping through the code to see what actually happens